# Handling Dynamic Image Directory in Django {% include "subtemplate.html" %}

Tags: html, django

I have a part of my html that I use in more than 5 pages of my site. I have extracted it out `subtemplate.html` and I now `{% include "subtemplate.html" %}` in all those templates. Plus I use [sorl-thumbnail](http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples.html) for my images.

The problem is these pages have different **urls** and that determine my image directory.

```
myApp/
images/
mysite/
manage.py
requirements.text
```

Now these are there urls with their image directory

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/mysite/               <img src=".{{ im.url }}" />
http://127.0.0.1:8000/mysite/more/10        <img src="../..{{ im.url }}" />
http://127.0.0.1:8000/mysite/new/more/10    <img src="../../..{{ im.url }}" />
```

This is working if I am not using `include` but if forces me to use same code in all the pages and that is costly for me.  The `"subtemplate.html"` has it image directory set to `<img src=".{{ im.url }}" />` and so the images get displayed in my app's home page but not on other pages.

But now that it is obvious that I have to use `include`, what is the best way to for me to change image directory dynamically base on the page including it?

Comment: Can you show the models with ImageField  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use

```
<img src="/mysite{{ im.url }}" />
```

The slash `/` will force the path to always start from the root directory.

Comment: Can you do the edit so that I can accept the answer?